# how to find the nearest values in jquery both decimal or floating point numbers

Tags: jquery

i am having one collection . The collection is below

```
X=[1940,1941,1943,1945,1978]
```

i want to find the nearest values from the above collection by passing some value (ex:**1944.578895**)

for `1944.57889` it will return `1945` and for `1943.5` it will return `1943` like that. the collection **"`X`"** will be varied that means it  contains floating numbers too.

so i want to find the nearest value for floating point collection as well numeric collection.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: possible duplicate of [using jquery, how would i find the closest match in an array, to a specified number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561275/using-jquery-how-would-i-find-the-closest-match-in-an-array-to-a-specified-num)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All numbers in Javascript are floating point so this should work just fine:

```
var theArray = [1940,1941,1943,1945,1978];
var goal = 1944.578895;
var closest = null;

$.each(theArray, function(){
  if (closest == null || Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(closest - goal)) {
    closest = this;
  }
});
```

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584929/390330

Comment: whether this will work floating point numbers.that means if am having  floating point collection as well passing floating point number too.

Comment: var array=[1945.6777,1978.27555,...]  var goal=1944.555 like that whether the above code will work for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `Math.abs`

```
 Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(closest - goal)
```

Refer this for full example  by @Guffa :

[using jquery, how would i find the closest match in an array, to a specified number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561275/using-jquery-how-would-i-find-the-closest-match-in-an-array-to-a-specified-num)