# Return array item for closest match in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is a close question to [using jquery, how would i find the closest match in an array, to a specified number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561275/using-jquery-how-would-i-find-the-closest-match-in-an-array-to-a-specified-num/3561328#3561328)

but I need help with the logic. I want to pass a value to getComparison and for it to return the nearest description.

```
function getComparison(measure) {

    var key;
    var measures = [];
    measures[1]     = 'Height of Gloucester old spot pig';
    measures[2]     = 'Length of a racehorse';
    measures[3]     = 'Width of a cricket pitch';
    measures[4]     = 'Length of a salt water crocodile';
    measures[5]     = 'Length of a large family car';
    measures[6]     = 'Length of a Luton Van';
    measures[7]     = 'Height of Cheltenham War Memorial';
    measures[10]    = 'Length of a killer whale';
//etc
    var closest = null;
    jQuery.each(measures, function(){
        if (closest == null || Math.abs(this - measure) < Math.abs(closest - measure)) {
        closest = this;
        }
    });
    console.log(closest);
    return closest;
}
```

Comment: ...this is a joke, right?

Comment: The scale numbers seem to be missing, or are those 1-10? Should they be linear like that?

Comment: No, it's sporadic as there aren't a full list of lengths ie there isn't a matching 8m or 9m length so I want to return the nearest.

Comment: You're subtracting the strings, not the indexes.

Comment: @Juhana are you always this helpful and constructive or are you just having a day off? Answer now accepted.

Comment: The question wasn't very clear, as evidenced by the downvotes; it looked like you wanted to compare strings that contained "funny" units of length (which is what the code in the question does). Congrats to Barmar for guessing the actual intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the lengths, not the strings.

```
var closest = null;
var closest_dist;
$.each(measures, function(length) {
    var dist = Math.abs(length - measure);
    if (closest === null || dist < closest_dist) {
        closest = length;
        closest_dist = dist;
    }
});
return measures[closest];
```

Comment: I don't see any lengths in the question.

Comment: @Andy The lengths are the indexes in his array.